# Multiple scraping flat-file for list of urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, libraries, flat-file

I made a script for scraping pages of some shop looking for out of stock items. It looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urls = ['https://www.someurla','https://www.someurlb']
for url in urls:
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
    if len(soup.find_all('li',class_='out-of-stock')) > 0:
        print(soup.title)
```

Now, I would like to somehow make this list or URLs available for updating without intervention in this little script. So, I think about some detached file that would serve as a flat database. I think it would be more appropriate than some relational DB, because I don't need it really.

I would like to get some opinion from more experienced Python users is this appropriate approach, and if it is what is the best way to do this with text or with .py file. What libraries are good for this task? On the other hand are there better approaches?

Comment: Use `scrapy`. It has the features you need

Answer (score 1):

Go with a simple JSON file. Something like this:

```py
import os
import json

url_file = '<path>/urls.json'
urls = []

if os.path.isfile(url_file):
    with open(url_file, 'rb') as f:
        urls = json.load(f)['urls']
else:
    print('No URLs found to load')

print(urls)

# hook in your script here...
```

JSON structure for this particular example:

```
{
    "urls": [
        "http://example.com",
        "http://google.com"
    ]
}
```